# Html include inside Jquery

Tags: jquery

Can i place html include inside Jquery?

Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

$(".photo").hoverIntent(function() {
    $(this).html('CAN I PLACE HERE A HTML INCLUDE?');
}, function() {
    $(this).html('<img src="' + $(this).attr("title") + '" width="248" height="186" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #2B2B2B;"/>');
});

});
```

Comment: Did you try it and you are having a problem?

Comment: what do you mean by `HTML INCLUDE`? a page? a piece of html? - the second one should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$(this).load('file.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not good, when i use load(file.html); it reddirects my site to that file only.

I just want to replace certain html on my page with jquery

Comment: Actually it loads the file into $(this), you need to specify what $(this) is. Typically it is a fragment of your original document.